# Simple #meteor subscribe call giving an error

Tags: javascript, meteor

Server :

```
Meteor.publish('trades', function() {
return Trades.find();
});
```

Client:

```
Meteor.subscribe("trades");
```

Both:

```
Trades = new Meteor.Collection('trades');
```

When I run meteor, its giving me

*TypeError: Object # has no method 'subscribe'*

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You might have your client code running in the root directory `/`. It would also then execute on the server and give this error. (Not sure if its this).